# What's wrong with this jquery animation function?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

```
animImage('history_main_image.png');
function animImage(img) {
    $('#slider').delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(img) {$('#slider').css('background-image','url(images/' + img +')').animate({opacity: 1});});
}
```

i have made it a function to animate the background in the slider element.but it doesn't work.when i check the output in chrome's inspect element option.it shows background-image:images/undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback you pass to `animate()` takes an `img` argument and uses it to build an URL to the background image. That won't work, because `animate()` does not pass any argument to your callback.

Instead, you can remove that argument and use the `img` argument originally passed to `animImage()`. That variable exists in the caller's scope, so it will be captured and accessible inside your callback:

```
function animImage(img)
{
    $('#slider').delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $('#slider').css('background-image', 'url(images/' + img +')')
                    .animate({opacity: 1});
    });
}
```

Comment: oh my go....it works!!...that's so good...actually i was using my php brain in javascript!!....thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
animImage('history_main_image.png');
function animImage(img) {
   function myimg(){return img;}
    $('#slider').delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {$('#slider').css('background-image','url(images/' + myimg() +')').animate({opacity: 1});});
}
```